# Appropriate design of DHTML / multipage CGI form

Tags: forms, cgi, dhtml

What is the standard method for implementing a "wizard" using successive web forms?

I'm implementing a CGI that accepts several options, files, etc. But some of these options have dependencies to one another, and allow or require other options to be used.

For example, one type of object that needs to be initialized by the CGI can be created using:

- two files of type X

  two strings

  one file of type Y

In my command line version, I look whether two files of type X, two strings, or one file of type Y is provided, and construct the object in the appropriate manner.

In my CGI, I'd like to do this using multiple pages or DHTML (perhaps a radio button that specifies which arguments the user wishes to provide; changing the radio button will change the form to the right).

Anyway, I have this situation for 3 main groups of arguments. I thought it would be pleasing to the user to create a 6 "page" wizard (think online dating):

**Page 1:**
*"How would you like to specify your proteins of interest?"*
radio button:

Two FASTA files

Prefix and suffix strings that match all of my proteins (and match *only* my proteins)

A text file containing the proteins

**Page 2:**
*"Great! Please choose your (either 'fasta files', 'prefix and suffix strings', or 'text file')."*
(appropriate web form)

Unfortunately, if the form is split over different pages, I'm not sure how the 3rd, 4th, etc. pages will know the location of the temporary folder created for the uploaded files from pages 1 and 2.

I'd really appreciate your advice; I have a good command line app, but I am having a difficult time making *beautiful* interface code that will do what I want. And I'd be shocked if there isn't a *very easy* standard way to do this with Django or some other framework; it just seems it must come up very frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a wizard plugin for jQuery.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/formwizard

If you don't know jQuery, it is a javascript framework for doing DHTML.

Try the demo at http://thecodemine.org/

Comment: While adding jQuery afterwards may be a nice enhancement, it's a good idea to design your application to first work without JavaScript and then enhance it with JavaScript.

Comment: Why is it a good idea?  There are ~4% of internet browser that have no javascript.  On a corporate network the number is probably 0%.  What would be good about avoiding the design potential of javascript and jQuery.  I don't understand why you wouldn't use it. It's there. It works.  It makes for a beautiful user experience.  It's easier than building it yourself. What's not to like?

Comment: I just don't think it's appropriate to force a portion of users to enable JavaScript where the same functionality (a wizard) can be produced without JavaScript without much hassle.

Comment: *Force them to enable Javascript*?  Are there really holdouts who refuse to use Javascript? Are they the same people who refuse to use that newfangled World Wide Web stuff? If your wizard is intended for an audience inside your organization, it can be safely assumed that they all have modern browsers with Javascript. If you refuse to assume that, you are living in 1997. You may as well distribute paper forms, because some people don't have web browsers. Obviously ridiculous.  ps: you tagged your post with the DHTML tag. DHTML presumes Javascript. DHTML = DOM manipulation via Javascript.

Comment: +1 both comments: Gracefully avoiding fancy plugins is a good point for some applications-- but for mine, I 'll throw an error and it's their choice to modernize or not. And to be honest, I just couldn't figure out how to do it well without JavaScript. The old world needs to die so the new world can be built on top!